# Serilog mssql sink SqlColumn data type

Tags: c#, serilog

I am attempting to add an additional column to my logging in SQL Server. In the examples, they give something very similar to the following:

```
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
        {
            AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
            {
                new SqlColumn { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, DataLength = 20, ColumnName = "B" }
            }
        }
```

The problem that I am having is that my compiler keeps complaining about the `SqlColumn` type usage saying that it is unknown. I am using .Net 4.6.1. What do I need to add to my using? I have the following already:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Owin;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Filters;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
using SerilogWeb.Classic.WebApi;
```

---

EDIT

I have just attempted building an entire new web api project, and the following code also will not work, for some reason I cannot access the SqlColumn type. Note that the error is that the type doesn't exist on the namespace (not an error due to the constructor).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestProject.Startup))]

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            var x = new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.SqlColumn();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is defined in Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer namespace acording to the source: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/2d1fa1bcbf36788d218dcfede758b046ed5b9f4c/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/SqlColumn.cs

Do you have the correct Nuget? Maybe this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/5.1.2 ?

Comment: @mortb, I even attempted to specify that explicitly and it errors saying `The type or namespace name 'SqlColumn' does not exist in the namespace 'Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Also, I am using the 5.1.2 version of the NuGet package

Comment: The only available classes that I can see on Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer are the following: ColumnOptions, MSSqlServerAuditSink, MSSqlServerSink, StandardColumn,  and XmlPropertyFormatter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to Update [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/5.1.3-dev-00232) to prereleased version *5.1.3-dev-00232* as its not exist in version *5.1.2*

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer -Version 5.1.3-dev-00232
```

Or you can add column using `DataColumn` type in version *5.1.2* as below

```
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<DataColumn>
    {
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof (string), ColumnName = "User"},
        new DataColumn {DataType = typeof (string), ColumnName = "Other"},
    }
};

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LogEvents;Trusted_Connection=True;", "Logs", columnOptions: columnOptions)
    .CreateLogger();
```